# C++ function is being called before page loads even with Component.onCompleted

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qt-creator

Here is the issue, I created a C++ class which loads a local file and for every new line it sends out a signal. What I want to do is in my QML file I want to print out these lines into a listview which I have already done but the issue now is that the C++ function loads even before the application starts, it would read the file and populate the listview and then display the page.

Here is my code.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickView>
#include <QtQml>


#include "boot.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("xyz");
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_X11InitThreads);

    qmlRegisterType<Boot>("xyx", 1, 0, "Boot");

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView quickView;
    quickView.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/Boot.qml")));
    quickView.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    quickView.showMaximized();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**Boot.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import "."
import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.0
import xyz 1.0

Item{

    Loader{
        id: bootPageLoader
        anchors.fill:parent
        sourceComponent: bootSystem
        focus:true
    }

    Component{
        id:bootSystem

        Rectangle{
            width: 640
            height: 480
            color:"black"
            focus:true

            Component.onCompleted: {
                booting.load();
            }

            Boot{
                id:booting

                onErrorMsgChanged: {
                     console.log("New Boot Log Message: " + errorMsg);
                     //This is where I am adding to the listview every time I receive a signal 
                     logModel.append({msg:errorMsg});
                     log.positionViewAtEnd();


                }
           }

           ListView {
               id:log
               anchors.left: parent.left
               anchors.leftMargin: 10
               anchors.topMargin: 10
               anchors.bottomMargin:10
               anchors.top: parent.top
               width:(parent.width*40)/100
               height:parent.height-20

               model: BootLogModel{
                   id:logModel
               }
               delegate: Text {
                   text: msg
                   color: "green"
                   font.pixelSize: 15
               }
           }

           Text{
               id: loading
               anchors{
                   horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                   verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
               }

               text: "LOADING..."
               color: "white"
               font.pixelSize: Math.round(parent.height/20)
               font.bold: true
           }
       }
   }
}
```

**BootLogModel.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
ListModel {

}
```

Here is the C++ code snippet

**In boot.h**

```
#ifndef BOOT_H
#define BOOT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <string>

class Boot : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString errorMsg READ errorMsg NOTIFY errorMsgChanged)

    public:
        explicit Boot(QObject *parent = 0);
        Q_INVOKABLE void load();

        QString errorMsg();
        void setErrorMsg(const QString &errorMsg);

    signals:
        void errorMsgChanged();
    private:
        QString m_errorMsg;
};
#endif // BOOT_H
```

**In boot.cpp**

```
Boot::Boot(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}
QString Boot::errorMsg()
{
    return m_errorMsg;
}

void Boot::setErrorMsg(const QString &errorMsg)
{
    m_errorMsg = errorMsg;

    emit errorMsgChanged();
}

void Boot::load()
{
    int i = 0;
   while(i < 10000)
   {
       setErrorMsg("test: " + QString::number(i));
       i++;
   }

}
```

I first see this before the GUI
[image: I first see this before the GUI]

Then this is the GUI being displayed and already populated
[image: Then this is the GUI being displayed and already populated]

Comment: If your problem is to print this data then I have a solution for that specific case, you should also know that the loops are not GUI friendly.

Comment: Please put up the solution it might work. The issue is not with the loop, what I want to do is whenever I call "SetErrorMsg" I want it to add the message to the listview and update the gui. I want to do this in any other function.

Comment: say I have a function called "play" what I want to do is if play has an error then I want to set the error message and emit a signal which will update the gui when it changess.

Comment: I think in normal situations it will do, but when there is a loop there are always problems, the best is to use more friendly things like in this case a QTimer with period zero. In the next link is my solution, if it works you will notify me to publish it as a response: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/11ae5d8b07c6c4b9bd0c0ef52ed4335e

Comment: That works perfect if it's a loop with a number condition, what if I want to read a file? and I don't know the number of lines?

Comment: You could show me the code of how to read a file and I will try to convert it to that form.

Comment: In addition to a file that generates the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loops are always a problem in a GUI, it is always better to look for a friendlier alternative to the GUI, in this case a `QTimer`:

**boot.h**

```
int counter = 0;
```

**bool.cpp**

```
void Boot::load()
{
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);

    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [timer, this](){
        setErrorMsg("test: "  + QString::number(counter));
        counter++;
        if(counter > 10000){
            timer->stop();
            timer->deleteLater();
        }
    });
    timer->start(0); //delay
}
```